# MySQL Workbench Cannot start SSH tunnel manager

Tags: networking, mysql, ssh-tunneling, slackware

I don't know why this error is happening when I try to connect by MySQL Workbench.

> Cannot start SSH tunnel manager.

I'm using slackware 14.1 and installed all dependencies.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the MySQL server is running and you have the proper credentials to get into it? Also is there any firewall between you and the DB server that may be preventing your connections?

Comment: What version are you using of Workbench?

Comment: I'm using version 6.1

Comment: There is no firewall turned on and the User root has all the permissions on localhost but does not connect with the WorkBanch.

Comment: Can you run mysql workbench in a console/terminal and paste the contents of the msgs from there here please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have access to Slackware but I believe you need to install the Python binding/wrapper libraries for `paramiko` as well. At least that's the case on Fedora/CentOS and other distros from what I can gather from this forum post titled: [MySQL Forums :: MySQL Workbench :: Ubuntu: Cannot start SSH tunnel manager](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,509854,525065#msg-525065).

> thanks ! 
>   install python-paramiko solve my problem.

If that doesn't resolve your issue there may be some packages missing/corrupt that require re-installation. Again this tip comes from that same thread I mentioned above and is directed towards Ubuntu, but may shed some light on what's wrong in your particular case.

> Posted by: Roman Schaller () Date: July 02, 2012 04:00PM
>
> Although I had the same problem, this was not the solution to my
>   Ubuntu 12.4. I solved it this way:
>
> First I checked what was logged to the console if I start the workbench
>   from command line. There I could see some more details:
>
> ```
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py",
>     line 28, in <module>  from Crypto.Random import OSRNG  ImportError:
>     cannot import name OSRNG
> ```
>
> This lead me to reinstall some python crypto packages with synaptic. I
>   reinstalled following packages:
>
> ```
>     python (2.7.3-0ubuntu2)  python-all
>     (2.7.3-0ubuntu2)  python-appindicator (0.4.92-0ubuntu1)  python-apport
>     (2.0.1-0ubuntu10)  python-apt (0.8.3ubuntu7)  python-apt-common
>     (0.8.3ubuntu7)  python-aptdaemon (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2) 
>     python-aptdaemon-gtk (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2) 
>     python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2) 
>     python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2) 
>     python-aptdaemon.pkcompat (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu2)  python-avahi
>     (0.6.30-5ubuntu2)  python-beautifulsoup (3.2.0-2build1)  python-cairo
>     (1.8.8-1ubuntu3)  python-crypto (2.4.1-1ubuntu0.1) 
>     python-gnomekeyring (2.32.0+dfsg-1)  python-gnupginterface
>     (0.3.2-9.1ubuntu3)  python-mysql.connector (0.3.2-1)  python-oauth
>     (1.0.1-3build1)  python-openssl (0.12-1ubuntu2)  python-paramiko
>     (1.7.7.1-2)  python-pycryptopp (0.5.29-1build1)
> ```
>
> I'm pretty sure only one of them was the cause of my problem. Probably
>   python-openssl or python-paramiko. I can't test it again. Maybe
>   someone else can figure it out...

Answer (score 4):

install packages pycrypto and paramiko, download in slackbuilds.org.

Comment: I already installed pyCrypto and paramiko, I installed all the dependencies!

Comment: i have this similiar problem, after reading what @CelsoNery suggested, seem the pycrypto is not installed yet. In my case, installing pycrypto solved the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this question.  I ran into this problem on Fedora 20 and discovered, duhhhh, that I had installed the 32-bit version of mysql-workbench on 64-bit Fedora 20 instead of the 64-bit version.  After uninstalling the 32-bit version:

```
$ sudo yum remove mysql-workbench
```

and installing the 64-bit version instead

```
$ sudo yum localinstall mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

I fired it up and it worked no problems.  No doubt you do have to have `python-paramik` etc. installed as others have said, but on Fedora 20 that all seemed to be fine.  The whole problem was the 32-bit version of `mysql-workbench`.

Comment: This was also the answer for me using the latest 64-bit deb and installing with Ubuntu Software Center.