# Anyone know a good gui to MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, gui, slackware, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB instead of MySQL in Slackware 14.1, and I need a graphic manager like MySQL Workbench. Can anyone suggest me something?
I tried using MySQL WorkBench but it could not connected with MariaDB.

Comment: This question is still useful thought even if closed. Maybe it could be migrated in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The MariaDB FAQ has the following topic covering exactly this question, titled: [GUI/Workbench for MariaDB Aria?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiworkbench-for-mariadb-aria/).

> There are many GUI tools that work with MariaDB, such as [Webyog/SQLyog](http://webyog.com/), [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), and of course, [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).
>
> We know some tools have received requests and/or are working to add support for MariaDB and Aria-specific features ([SQLyog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/issues/detail?id=538), for example). Until your preferred GUI tool supports MariaDB and Aria-specific features directly, most of the tools provide a mechanism for editing and executing custom SQL code.

One of the comments also suggested this tool:

> Devart dbForge Studio is a universal MySQL GUI tool. [dbForge Studio for MySQL v.6.1](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) now works with any MariaDB database servers, and supports all MariaDB objects types. You can visually design database structures, execute SQL queries and scripts, and manage MariaDB users and their privileges.

Comment: I installed this http://www.jpdbadmin.com/

Functioned normally, i have also installed MySQL WorkBench but it does not work, the following error occurs:

Can not start SSH tunnel manager.

I even asked about this issue here:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129444/mysql-workbench-cannot-start-ssh-tunnel-manager

But the answers were not useful!

Could you help me?

Comment: +1 for **[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)** !

Comment: MySQL Workbench has been horribly broken for 3+ years and does NOT work well with MariaDB 10.x.  I just tried this today and it has no support to even BUILD against a MariaDB 10 client. If you take binaries built against MySQL 6.x or 5.x, and try to connect, it will warn, and connect, and then whole areas of the app do not work, including most of the stuff under the Server menu, such as the Users and Permissions.

Comment: @WarrenP More like 4 years now.

Comment: More like 8+ years. MySQL workbench for MariaDB in 2021 is worse than ever: slow, unstable, crashes and burns on almost every table alteration attempt. The other two suggestions are not only proprietary, but also Windows-only.

Comment: i was searching then found this: https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/